# Angular share data between controllers and components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new on a project and trying to add a small feature.

I have 2 views, `Cars.html` and `Wheels.html`

Cars.html has a controller `Cars.controller.js`

Wheels.html has a component `Wheels.component.js`

I want to communicate between these two controllers. I have tried directly injecting them into each other, but that causes a bunch of 'Provider errors'.

Through research online, it seems like I need a 'service' that gets injected by my *controller* and *component*... then I can make function calls between the two. Doing this resolves the provider errors, but I can't seem to access the `howDoIgetHere` function.

Here is what they look like:

**Cars.controller.js**

```
angular.module('Cars')
  .controller('CarsCtrl', CarsCtrl);

CarsCtrl.$inject = ['PartsViewModel'];
function CarsCtrl(PartsViewModel) {
  var ctrl = this;

  // This will fail
  ctrl.goToParts = PartsViewModel.howDoIgetHere();

};
```

**Wheels.component.js**

```
angular.module('Cars')
  .component('wheels', {
    bindings: { wheel: '=' },
    controller: 'WheelsCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/component/Cars/Wheels/Wheels.component.html'
  })
  .controller('WheelsCtrl', WheelsCtrl);

WheelsCtrl.$inject = [];
function WheelsCtrl() {
  var ctrl = this;

  // This will fail
  ctrl.goToParts = PartsViewModel.howDoIgetHere();

}
```

**PartsViewModel.service.js**

```
angular.module('Cars')
  .factory('PartsViewModel', partsViewModelFactory);

partsViewModelFactory.$inject = ['Some', 'injected', 'Dependencies'];
function partsViewModelFactory(Some, injected, Dependencies) {
  return PartsViewModel;

  function PartsViewModel(part) {

    this.howDoIgetHere = function() {
      console.log('Success! From Cars controller or Wheels component.')
    };

  }
}
```

**Cars.html**

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.goToParts()"></button>
</div>
```

**Wheels.html**

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="$ctrl.goToParts()"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your controller it should be `this.goToParts = PartsViewModel().howDoIgetHere;`

Second, in your service, the return statement should go after the function declaration.

edit: Sorry I misread what was causing the provider errors.

Edit 2:

If you're trying to access the same data set, you are defeating the purpose by creating a new instance of the PartsViewModel each time.

Change The partsviewmodel service to:

```
angular.module('mymodule').service('PartsViewService', PartsViewService);

 function PartsViewService(){
        var howDoIGetHere = function(){
            Console.log('here');
        };
        return {
            howDoIGetHere : howDoIGetHere
        }
    }
```

Then when accessing the injected service in your controllers.

```
this.goToParts = PartsViewService.howDoIGetHere;
```

<strike>Third, make sure that the provider error isn't caused by you misspelling the service name.</strike>

Comment: `ctrl` is a reference to `this` in my controller, so that isn't the problem. Removing the parenthesis after `howDoIgetHere()` doesn't do anything. Keeping it, gives me the error: "PartsViewModel.howDoIgetHere() is not a function".

Comment: I understood that. There's no difference either way. And by leaving the parenthesis in you are setting ctrl.goToParts to the return value of the function.

Comment: Oh interesting. So I should actually remove the parenthesis? If so, how do I call the function without the parenthesis?

Comment: there are about 15 other function properties in the `PartsViewModel`, I just posted a barebones example. I suppose that is why we are returning the entire function as opposed to individual properties.  So this return style won't work for me. Thanks for the update though, I appreciate it

Comment: Like I said, if you're looking to access the same data across multiple controllers, you will either need to have a singleton of some kind, or a separate, second service that holds the object instance who's data you want to access. There being other function properties has nothing to do with the return style, except for that it needs to come after the function declaration.

Comment: If you want to leave it how it is see the updated 1st recommended change.